# How to return subset of nested fields in MongoDB, where those fields match various conditions?

Tags: mongodb

I have a schema which is like this (still in the planning phase of how I will structure the schema for moving to MongoDB from JSON files):

```
{
  slug: 'string',
  transcriptions: [
    {
      system: 'foo',
      text: 'bar',
      is_main: true,
      generator: 'something',
      source: 'human'
    }
  ],
  pronunciations: [
    {
      system: 'foo',
      text: 'bar',
      is_main: true,
      generator: 'something',
      source: 'human'
    }
  ],
  definitions: [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I select out the transcriptions and pronunciations which have `is_main: true`, for 1000 words?

```
db.words.find({ slug: ['hello', 'world', ...moreWords] }, {
  slug: 1,
  'transcriptions.$': 1,
  'pronunciations.$': 1,
})
```

That seems like it would return all possible transcriptions/pronunciations, even if there are 20 in each nested array! I only want the one marked `is_main`. How can I do that?

Basically, how do I select a subset of fields which match various conditions?

```
db.words.find({ slug: { $in: ['a', 'b', ...] }, transcriptions: { $: { is_main: true } }, pronunciations: { $: { is_main: true } } })
```

Comment: If you are often querying on subdocument level (i.e. `transcriptions` / `pronunciations `), it is suggested to store the subdocuments as individual documents like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UNEQdj_9O_2). You gain the benefits of easy queries and performance advantage through indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregate for this type of query and only project the `transcriptions` and `pronunciations` that pass your `$filter` conditions like so:

```js
db.words.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      slug: {
        $in: [
          "string",
          "yellow",
          "blue"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      transcriptions: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$transcriptions",
          as: "tran",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$tran.is_main",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      pronunciations: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$pronunciations",
          as: "pron",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$pron.is_main",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      definitions: 1,
      slug: 1
    }
  }
])
```

See working example on [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nzj45uz747c).